# Spring Boot SockJS over stomp and Apache Artemis

Tags: spring-boot, stomp, spring-websocket, sockjs, activemq-artemis

I have a chat application I created using Spring Boot with SockJS over STOMP backed by and external ActiveMQ Broker, 
My issue is that after approximately 4000 client connection and 10000 ActiveMQ destinations, ActiveMQ crashes with out of memory relating to KahaDB.
I would like to switch to Apache Artemis as the blog mentioned it performs better than ActiveMQ and handles alot more client connection and also implements non-blocking in.
My hope was to just swap out ActiveMQ with Artemis, however, I see the clients connects and subscribe to topics and queues but they are not receiving the messages via Artemis.

And ideas what could be the issue?
Here is my settings in Artemis broker.xml config file:

```
  <address-settings>
     <!--default for catch all-->
     <address-setting match="#">
        <dead-letter-address>jms.queue.DLQ</dead-letter-address>
        <expiry-address>jms.queue.ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
        <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
        <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
        <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
        <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
        <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>

        <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
        <auto-delete-jms-queues>true</auto-delete-jms-queues>

     </address-setting>
  </address-settings>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With artemis, You should try the latest version available (1.5.2 at the time I'm writing this).

You probably need to change the address name and queue name accordingly with Artemis 1.x. (jms.queue and jms.topic) prefixes.

With the upcoming release of 2.0 the address model doesn't require prefixes any longer, but at the current version you may be hitting the issue of having to define prefixes on your application.

Feel free to start a discussion on the user's list, which is the place where contributors are mostly active.

Comment: Thanks Celebert for the quick response. Very much appreciated.
I am using the latest version 1.5.2. I will try it with the jms.queue and jms.topic predicate.
Any idea when 2.0 will be release?

Thanks

Comment: This is as in any software project.. we want to do it in 1 month (from the day I'm writing this, for future viewers).. but you know how that goes... 

I think it will be Feb Or match/2017.. based on the JIRAs left to be done.. but that's my personal prediction.

Comment: Thanks very much for the update, I will keep an eye out for the 2.0 release.

Comment: There's actually a message on the devlist about this today:

For future references: http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/DISCUSS-ActiveMQ-Artemis-2-x-stream-tp4721815.html;cid=1486677913100-504

Comment: Thanks Clebert- looking forward for he 2.0 release.

Comment: Hey Guys-
Is there a correlation between the number of destinations (queues/address) created on Artemis and performance? There is a potential for over 50,000 destinations and I was wondering if this is something I should be worried about in regards to performance and scalability?

Thanks

Comment: I would probably play with more than one broker instance. 50K seems you will need many clients, with many sockets.. beyond the limits of the hardware.

Comment: thanks Clebert. I will look into clustering Artemis and front my spring boot chat services with a load balancer or kubernetes with docker to spread the load horizontally. I will update this thread how that works out. Thank you and thanks for the awesome work you guys doing with Artemis!

Comment: I didn't say necessarily clustering. just keep them separate. no need to cluster. Just use multiple instances. Unless you need topics.

Why don't you open a new thread?

Comment: Can I get a vote or accept the question? :) It's nice to get points :)

Comment: Hi guys- I was using Artemis 1.5.3 and my addressing scheme was jms.topic.xxx for pub-sub and jms.queue.xxx for point to point and all worked great. However I switch to version 2.1.0 and the jms.topic.xxx work like a point to point routing, meaning not all subscribers receive the message. Previously, I was using ActiveMQ and their naming prefix was /topic.xxx and /queue.xxx.
I also tried setting the multicast config in broker.xml per http://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/2.1.0/address-model.html but Artemis is complaining and will not start. 
Any help would be much appreciated.